# tabplot graph theme color

Tags: r, bar-chart, large-data

[image: Table plot bar chart space]I'm using tabplot package to visualize my data set. How is it possible to change the color of the space between the barcharts in tableplot? In the following graph the color of the spaces is white, how can we change it into another color? I marked the spaces with arrows in the attached plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tabplot)
data("diamonds")
tableplot(diamonds)
```

Comment: Check your code in a fresh R session - it's not working.

Comment: Great question! the package documentation says nothing about the theme color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is far from being easy to answer. But I can give some of the ideas I find.
The problem is that `tabplot-object` are neither `ggplot` nor `plot` object.

So we must look at the `viewport` and `grid.layout` parameter of the graph. I'm not used to that type of things. My solution is :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tabplot)
library(grid)
data("diamonds")
tplot <- tableplot(diamonds, plot = F)

grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="red",col="black", alpha = 1))
plot(tplot, vp = viewport(width = 1, height = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: no, I still get the white default color in the space between the bars

Comment: I would like to change the color in the space between the bars